# How can an object refer to itself despite being lost in memory?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I'm making a DBMS in Tkinter and I want to have a button that will delete the corresponding entry (the entry to the right of it). How would the computer know what button is sending the command or is linked to what entry (or how do I link them)

Take a look at the following code

```py
def edit_db():
    for i in root.winfo_children():
        i.grid_remove()

    back_btn = Button(root, text='<--', command=home)
    back_btn.place(height=30, width=30, x=4, y=4)

    row_count = 1
    for i in cur.execute("SELECT * FROM students").fetchall():
        
        save_btn = Button(root, text='Save', font=("Calbri", 9))
        if row_count == 1: save_btn.grid(row=row_count, column=1, pady=(45, 3), padx=(5, 10))
        else: save_btn.grid(row=row_count, column=1, pady=3, padx=(5, 10))

        del_btn = Button(root, text="X", font=("Calbri", 9), command=del_entry)
        if row_count == 1: del_btn.grid(row=row_count, column=0, pady=(45, 3), padx=5)
        else: del_btn.grid(row=row_count, column=0, pady=3, padx=(5))
```

As you can see their are multiple `del_btn` (and `save_btn`) and their variable names will no longer correspond, but I want do something like

```
del_btn = Button(root, text="X", font=("Calbri", 9), command=del_entry(**self/this/me**))
```

Is there something I can do? Do I have to do this all in a `class` (I'm not very good a OOP so I don't know what difference it would make)? Or am I missing something and their is way to link each button with the entries in the database.

Here is my picture of my app, if it will help

[image]

Comment: append those entry widgets to a list and pass the index as an argument to the delete function, then in the function delete them from the list or more like, call `.destroy()` so that the rest of the indexes stay the same, or use a dictionary and delete the key, hint: use `lambda i=i` or sth similar to keep the index of the current loop and stuff

Comment: @Matiiss Yes, but how would I pass the index? Each button will have the same line of code, I added the entries widgets to and list (I also tried with a dictionary) but when passing it in it all button outputs would be the same (because like I said same line of code). Is there something I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: you are missing the part where I told you to use `lambda variable=variable:` (where variable can be any name you want...) which will allow the function to always use the same variable, in this case the index, so when you call the function of a particular button, it has "saved" its index, there is also two slightly different approaches I can think of that basically do the same but at least figure this out, if you can't I will try to write an answer

Comment: Also, I just read that you asked about classes, well, I don't know if it would be easier (not harder either) but I would say it would be better and would keep things more organized, if you want to I could try writing an example of that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution (includes 3 options):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label


label_list = []


def destroy_widget(index):
    label_list[index].destroy()


root = Tk()

for i in range(10):
    lbl = Label(root, text=f'Label {i}')
    lbl.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    label_list.append(lbl)

    Button(root, text=f'Destroy {i}',
           command=lambda index=i: destroy_widget(index)).grid(row=i, column=1, sticky='nsew')
    
    # option using partial (place import at the top)
    # from functools import partial
    # Button(root, text=f'Destroy {i}',
    #        command=lambda: partial(destroy_widget, i).grid(row=i, column=1, sticky='nsew')
    
    # option defining function here (if so then the one at the top isn't needed)
    # def destroy_widget(index=i):
    #     label_list[index].destroy()
    # Button(root, text=f'Destroy {i}',
    #        command=destroy_widget).grid(row=i, column=1, sticky='nsew')

root.mainloop()
```

As I said, put the widgets in a list, then save index (probably better use a dictionary and save the key so that they can be deleted altogether with their instance, otherwise you can't delete them from the list because that should change other indexes which is gonna mess things up) to the function you are passing to the button so that they "remember" it, I provided 3 different (slightly) ways to do this, one is using anonymous functions, one is using partial, one is using normal functions